# How to reverse hashed SHA256 with salt to original string ? I have salt

Tags: encryption, hash, sha256, sha, salt

I have a csv document with data that was hashed using SHA256 and I have the salt. Can someone please recommend me the best way to unhash the data only having the hash and the salt used ? I searched on google but I didn`t find any online convertors. Thanks

Comment: You can't "reverse" a hash: https://www.techsolvency.com/passwords/dehashing-reversing-decrypting/

Comment: there are many more question and answers about that. Search for hash together with unhash, reverse, decrypt... And it doesn't matter which kind of hash, md5, sha256,....

Comment: There is one way and one way only: try all possible input in all possible binary forms together with the known salt (and using the correct protocol, SHA-256 itself doesn't take a salt, just a single message input). This may not be very useful for an entire CSV file though.